# Derivative inside Fourier integral

Tags: fourier-transform

I have two wave modes in moving frames

$a(s,z) = A(s + z/c,z)$ and $b(s,z) = B(s - z/c,z).$

I define

$\hat a(\omega,z) = \int e^{i\omega s}a(s,z)ds$ and $\hat b(\omega,z) = \int e^{i\omega s}b(s,z)ds$ where $t = s + z/c.$

I can show that

$$\begin{align}\int e^{i\omega s}\frac{\partial A}{\partial s}(s + z/c,z)\,ds = -i\omega\int a(s,z)ds
\end{align}$$

since

$$\begin{align}\frac{\partial A}{\partial s} = \frac{\partial a}{\partial s} = -i\omega \hat a(\omega,s)\end{align}.$$

But I am having trouble now computing

$$\begin{align}
\int e^{i\omega s} \frac{\partial A}{\partial t}(s + z/c,z)\,ds
\end{align}$$

Could someone offer a hint please?

Comment: What is $t$ in the last formula?

Comment: $t=s+z/c$ as written on line 5